# How come my html-node keeps the class ng-hide the attribute ng-show=true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a radio input that looks like this:

```
<input name='{{inputName}}' type='radio' value='{{label}}' ng-model='key' id='{{name}}'>
```

The label is Press and the key is entry.182494741. If I click the input and have {{entry.182494741}} in my template, it outputs Press, so everything seems to work out allright.

I have some html that I want to be visible only when that radio is clicked:

```
  <gd-input-field ng-show="{{entry.182494741 == 'Press'}}" label="Specify media" name="specifymedia" key="entry.1570049241"></gd-input-field>{{entry.182494741}}
```

When I inspect the element and toggle between the various input-buttons, the attribute ng-show  remains, but element keeps the attribute ng-hide.

Comment: Have you tried `ng-show="entry.182494741 == 'Press'"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
<gd-input-field ng-show="entry.182494741 == 'Press'" label="Specify media" name="specifymedia" key="entry.1570049241"></gd-input-field>{{entry.182494741}}
```

The expression in ngShow should not have {{}}. Or the value will not be evaluated correctly.

Comment: worked like a charm! I keep confusing those, what's the reason to use or not use {{}} or {}

Comment: Inside the directives like ngShow, AngularJS knows it is a directive and will compile / call $eval automatically. While in the HTML, angular can't tell whether a 'name="abc"' should be compiled and linked with a scope. So we need to tell Angular this is a value we want to bind to the scope. So we need {{ }} clearly.